# Using webpack and libraries that use webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Scenario: I have an application where I use webpack to build myApp.js, I need to use externalLibrary.js that is a library that was built using webpack as well.

1. Can I include both of them side by side? (I assume the webpack bootstrap would effectively be loaded twice - Is that an issue?)

   ```
   <script src="externalLibrary.js"></script>
   <script src="myApp.js"></script>
   ```
2. If I do something like `var externalLib = new ExternalLibrary()` in myApp, and both myApp and externalLibrary use jQuery or some other 3rd party library; Will my bundle include include the externalLibrary (accounting for it's webpack config?) and do the tree shaking and everything? Will the jQuery code be duplicated or just include the code neccessary for externalLibrary and myApp?

How do I go about using webpack in my app that uses an external library also built with webpack? Is my code and the library code share a dependency, is that dependency loaded once or twice?

Answer (score 0):

I think to answer your question in detail a little more information is required:

- Do you build the external library within the same webpack project/instance or is it a different project with it's own webpack configuration?
- Is the external library referenced in your `package.json` as dependency? Or directly embedded in your project (e. g. in an own folder)?

Here some points that might help you already:

- If you do `var externalLib = new ExternalLibrary()` several times, it will create several instances of that ExternalLibrary. This is not a responsibility with Webpack, but with your code. Create it once and reference it everywhere if you want to instantiate it only once.
  What Webpack does is, that it makes sure that the constructor of that library is included in your `myApp.js` only once, when you do `const ExternalLib = require('external-lib')`.
- Webpack by default will just annotate dead code, but not remove it (tree shaking) unless you use a plugin like `UglifyJSPlugin`, [as shown in the docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).
- If you include the same file multiple times (even other packages e. g. `require('jquery')` are first included by their "main" file), it will be resolved only once by webpack and then be referenced in the code wherever used.